# SQL Server : cannot update column in table

Tags: sql-server

I cannot work out why my column is not being updated.

I have added a new column to an existing table as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE dbname..tablename 
  ADD RejectedCode [varchar](5) NULL
```

When I run the query below:

```
UPDATE dbname..tablename 
SET RejectedCode = 'OTHER',
    Notes = 'DEBUG'
WHERE RecordID = 12345
```

it says:

```
(1 row(s) affected)
```

I check the respective record and I can see the `Notes` column updated, but the new column still displays NULL and I don't get any error message.

What am I doing wrong?  Many thanks for help.

Comment: Can you run this and check?

select RejectedCode ,Notes from dbname..table RecordID = 12345

Comment: I just did and got NULL for rejected code and 'DEBUG' for Notes field

Comment: maybe you have trigger "instead of update" on your table?

Comment: please, provide a "desc dbname.tablename" and a select from before and after the update command.

Comment: Good point Ruslan, thanks! You're right, I found this trigger: INSTEAD OF DELETE,UPDATE.  I'm going to check what's going on in those 287 lines of legacy code...

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you have trigger `instead of update` on your table

Comment: For the benefit of others:  this was the correct answer to my problem. I modified the respective trigger and now it works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of updating directly try dynamic query like below,

```
 EXEC('Update dbname..tablename    SET RejectedCode = ''OTHER'',
        Notes = ''DEBUG'' WHERE RecordID = 12345')
```

Answer (score 1):

Seem like there is a `INSTEAD OF UPDATE` trigger on your table. to find out 
triggers associated with the table do as below.

In object explorer go to your table-name and click on triggers node.

or use the below code

```
SELECT 
     sysobjects.name AS trigger_name 
    ,USER_NAME(sysobjects.uid) AS trigger_owner 
    ,s.name AS table_schema 
    ,OBJECT_NAME(parent_obj) AS table_name 
    ,OBJECTPROPERTY( id, 'ExecIsUpdateTrigger') AS isupdate 
    ,OBJECTPROPERTY( id, 'ExecIsDeleteTrigger') AS isdelete 
    ,OBJECTPROPERTY( id, 'ExecIsInsertTrigger') AS isinsert 
    ,OBJECTPROPERTY( id, 'ExecIsAfterTrigger') AS isafter 
    ,OBJECTPROPERTY( id, 'ExecIsInsteadOfTrigger') AS isinsteadof 
    ,OBJECTPROPERTY(id, 'ExecIsTriggerDisabled') AS [disabled] 
FROM sysobjects 

INNER JOIN sysusers 
    ON sysobjects.uid = sysusers.uid 

INNER JOIN sys.tables t 
    ON sysobjects.parent_obj = t.object_id 

INNER JOIN sys.schemas s 
    ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id 

WHERE sysobjects.type = 'TR' 
and s.name = 'your table name'
```